# Android Studio change default app directory

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create an Android studio project which contains 3 modules:

- MyGameLib
- MyGamePro
- MyGameFree

I create an empty project, which has default module "app" and there is a default directory "app" in the project root folder. I add two additional module, MyGameLib and MyGameFree, so far everything is OK.

But when I tried to rename the modue 'app' to 'MyGamePro', only the module name is changed in Android studio. The folder name is still 'app'.

If I manually change the folder path name from 'app' to 'MyGamePro', the module becomes incorrect in the studio (becomes empty).

Please refer to the screenshot, I only changed module 'app' to 'MyGamePro', but in windows explorer, folder path is still 'app'.

[image: Screenshot of Studio and WindowsExplorer]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: When you say "rename", I gather you mean refactor.

Comment: Yes, I use alt+shift+R

Comment: Post a screenshot of your project structure so I can see what you're trying to do. Also, I gather "folder name" refers to a directory on the hard disk. If so, this directory won't be renamed when you refactor the module name within AS, as refactoring only change the project's definition within AS, not operating system's definition outside of AS- in this case, directory's name.

Comment: See my comment above. So, in effect, you will also need to rename "app" within Windows to "MyGamePro". Then, relink the new directory's name within AS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to refactor the module as opposed to changing the filename, this will automatically change all the required files (e.g. Manifest) in the studio so they are not incorrect.

- Right click the module name: app, Refactor -> Rename (to myApp, click ok)

If so a couple of good points are made towards the end of this article about management of adding multiple and priorities which may be of some help.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#ReferencingLibraryModule